# Вызов отладчика Visual Studio из другого IDE

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Существуют всякие простенькие IDE в которых можно писать код.

Так вот, некоторые умеют при запуске отладки, запускать отладку непосредственно в Visual Studio: т.е при запуске вылетает диалоговое окно с выбором дебаггера, где можно выбрать конкретную версию Visual Studio. При этом виден код, который писался в другой IDE и можно ставить точки останова и все другие вещи.

За счет чего достигается такая возможность?

Comment: Может, те простенькие IDE используют инструменты сборки от MS, которые формируют PDB-файл, который и содержит отладочную информацию?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, не исключено. Однако, каким образом левая IDE говорит VISUAL STUDIO "отладь этот код"?

Comment: Хороший вопрос... Я бы начал с process explorer'а (или process monitor? путаю их) и посмотрел что и как запускается...

Comment: Конкретизируй вопрос: ты хочешь узнать как открывается окно с выбором отладчика или почему при открытии студии виден код, который писался в другой IDE?

Comment: @Grundy, думаю, что и то и то интересно.

Comment: @iluxa1810, я к тому, что лучше разделить это на два разных вопроса

Comment: @Grundy, мне казалось, что это взаимосвязано и ответ на первый вопрос сразу же отвечает на второй.

Comment: @iluxa1810, это не связанные между собой вопросы

Comment: @iluxa1810 Такое же окошко выскакивает, если в программе вставить вызов метода [Debugger.Launch()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch(v=vs.110).aspx). Видимо используется или это или что-то похожее. 
Ну а код виден или за счет файлов символов (pdb) или за счет того, что в отладочной версии программы хранятся пути ссылающиеся на исходную папку\файлы и Visual Studio в состоянии их сопоставить и открыть.

Comment: Подозреваю что для отладки нужно знать как общаться с процессом VSDebugger или аналогичным, выполняющим функцию сервера-хостера запускаемого код. Аналогично тому как это делается в скриптовых языках. PDB файл тоже понадобится, вот только не уверен для чего - известно что там отладочная информация, но какая - нужно смотреть в документации.

Comment: Добавил конкретный ответ - как из другого приложения (или коммандной строки) запустить дебаг в Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

**Visual Studio** - это просто IDE, хотя и очень хорошая.
Но создание проектов, шаблоны проектов, компиляция, сборка, отладка - все это осуществляется средствами **Windows SDK и .NET Framework**.

**Вот конкретный ответ на ваш вопрос**:
Когда установлена Visual Studio - с ней установлена утилита devenv. И с помошью нее можно из коммандной строки запустить дебаг напрямую в VS, вот так:

```
Devenv /debugexe ExecutableFile
```

[ТУТ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241274.aspx) полное описание.

По сути все что нужно для разработки - это просто пакет утилит, которые вы можете запускать из коммандной строки, а код редактировать в любом текстовом редакторе.
Дебаг выполняется вот [этой](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/mdbg-exe) утилитой. Просто сама же студия ее и запускает (или напрямую dll через api - есть описания).
Вот [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/index) полный перечень утилит.

В случае **.NET Core** - все то же самое + мультиплатформенность.
Вот [мой ролик](https://youtu.be/xFfZRCaJCOM) про создание .net приложения на линуксе.
Вот мой ролик про создание MVC приложения на линкусе в docker контейнере.
(не добавляется сюда как ссылка, полная ссылка - https://youtu.be/E6GJ__dFPXM)

Comment: А за что минус?

Comment: :) Это адепты GUI обиделись на коммандные строки :)

Comment: @VladD, подозреваю, что минус за то, что это ответ на какой-то другой вопрос. Вопрос: программа запущена сама по себе, но при ошибке её можно отлаживать в VS - как это сделано? Ответ: Чтобы отлаживать в VS надо вместо программы запустить вот такую команду. Сам по себе ответ хороший, но отвечает он на какой-то другой вопрос, а не на заданный. Поставил плюс, чтоб был с нулевым рейтингом.

Comment: Ответ именно на вопрос "за счет чего достигается возможность запуска дебага в студии из другой иде?"

Comment: Ответ полностью конкретный - именно так как я описал это и делают.